# how to fix rendering error display in preview layer geoserver?

Tags: gis, geoserver

I publish my layer in geoserver, when i want to display it, i click in preview layer, they show me this error of rendering geoserver.

this error display if i load shapefile from Database or just from any folder in my computer. what is the problem exactely and what should i do to solve this error showing in preview layer geoserver  please?

[image]

Comment: look in geoserver logs

Comment: what should i change in geoserver logs?

Comment: Change nothing, look for stack traces, see if that gives you a hint of what the issue is. If not, post the full stack trace here.